# css nested selector for inner div

Tags: html, css

I have the below html structure

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="content-item">
      <span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <div>
          <div>    // OVerride class for this div
           Override class to this div
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I am looking to have a nested class which will override the style for very inner div.

The Div with comment Override class for this div should be overridden.
What is the best practice nested selector for this kind of situation.

Comment: The only way to override inline style is by using `!important` keyword beside the CSS rule. But it is not recommended.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your use case ?

Comment: You could try removing the `style` attribute on the server side, or with JavaScript.

Comment: I am looking for a nested selector

Comment: Have you searched basic CSS operators?

Comment: Inline styles are high up in priority over selectors, they even overrule IDs. The only selector able to override an inline style would have to include `!important`, as stated by Soothran.

Comment: Probably I was not clear, I am looking for a syntax where I can identify the div like col-md-6>div>span(2)>div>div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the html structure will not change, you can use the below CSS to override the `div`.

Mind it, it **WILL NOT** override any **inline styles** given in the `div`.

Also, try to avoid using very large nested selectors in future.

```css
.col-md-6>.content-item>span>div>div {
  color: green;
  // Your styles
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="content-item">
    <span>
      </span>
    <span>
        <div>
          <div> 
           Override class to this div
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>

  </div>
</div>
```